# MySql VIEW remove subquery in FROM condition

Tags: mysql

im really newbie with my sql and im trying to create some views buts mysql yell with error

> ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM
>   clause

how can i remove subquery in FROM condition and get the same results in a view?

```
SELECT actual, 
        curr, 
        CASE WHEN actual > anterior THEN 'raise' 
            WHEN actual < anterior THEN 'drop' ELSE 'nothing' 
        END as 'status' 
FROM ( 
        SELECT o.i_price as actual, o.i_currency as curr, 
            (
                SELECT i.i_price 
                FROM Info i 
                WHERE i.i_article_id = 1 
                  AND i.i_insert < o.i_insert 
                ORDER BY i.i_insert DESC LIMIT 1
            ) AS anterior 
        FROM Info o 
        WHERE o.i_article_id = 1 
        ORDER BY o.i_insert 
        DESC LIMIT 1 ) as q
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dinamica subquery during the creation of a view so you should  create a proper view for subquery

```
    create view my_q as 
    SELECT o.i_price as actual, o.i_currency as curr, 
                (
                    SELECT i.i_price 
                    FROM Info i 
                    WHERE i.i_article_id = 1 
                      AND i.i_insert < o.i_insert 
                    ORDER BY i.i_insert DESC LIMIT 1
                ) AS anterior 
            FROM Info o 
            WHERE o.i_article_id = 1 
            ORDER BY o.i_insert 
            DESC LIMIT 1
```

and the call the view in your top view

```
    create  view my_top_view as  
    SELECT actual, 
            curr, 
            CASE WHEN actual > anterior THEN 'raise' 
                WHEN actual < anterior THEN 'drop' ELSE 'nothing' 
            END as 'status' 
    FROM  my_q;
```

With this  the performance will suffer .. but to overcome the error you must not use subquery dynamics .. if you can is definitely better to rewrite the query .

Comment: performance wise, this is even more desastrous for database performance that the subquery in the from clause itself. well, at least it would work. Better would be to rewrite the query instead of stacking a temporary table on a temporary table. MySQL has it's reasons to forbid such inception.

Comment: @Kaii  I agree on the fact that the performance will suffer .. but to overcome the error you must not use subquery dynamics .. if you can is definitely better to rewrite the query .. I add this suggestion to answer too.

Answer (score 0):

View's select contains a subquery error: You can solve this. Use mysql mysqlworkbench to connect mysql DB. and run create view script from mysqlworkbench. It will work